# How to enable reverse DNS for private ips inside an Azure (ARM) virtual network

Tags: azure, virtual-network

Let's take a pretty straighforward setup, all in a dedicated resource group:

- 1 vnet (say `10.0.0.0/16`)
- 1 subnet (say `10.0.0.0/24`)
- 2 Linux virtual machines, `machine1` and `machine2` (with a public ip)

Once the machines are spun up, let's say `machine1` got ip `10.0.0.4` and `machine2` got `10.0.0.5`.

Once connected to any of these, I expected commands such as :

```
host 10.0.0.4
host 10.0.0.5
```

To properly resolve to the internal FQDNs of the hosts, which is something like `machine1.azelkjzerlqkzjfkljsqfjsf.fx.internal.cloudapp.net`.

I expected it to work right out of the box as it does on AWS. But it doesnt. There is a ton of resources about reverse DNS on public IPs, but it's not my problem. I cannnot find any valuable insight about reverse DNS on internal IPs.

Any idea how to to get it right ?

Edit: Since this question has been asked and answered, Azure added the private DNS support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reverse DNS for internal IPs in Azure. You have to provide name resolution using your own DNS Server. Additionally, "*machine1.azelkjzerlqkzjfkljsqfjsf.cloudapp.net*" is not an internal FQDN. It's a public FQDN. You can enable reverse DNS for the Public IP though.

Check table at the top:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances

And more info about running your own DNS Server

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-using-your-own-dns-server

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Internal FQDNS *do* have `.internal.cloudapp.net` tho, just forgot to mention the internal part.

Comment: This is the accepted answer for me because the new paid-for feature is a whole new thing for private domains, when I just need reverse for existing fqdns.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Bruno Faria](https://serverfault.com/users/218644/bruno-faria) said that `machine1.azelkjzerlqkzjfkljsqfjsf.cloudapp.net` is not a internal FQDN, it's a public FQDN.  I understand why you want to use this feature , but now we should do something else to achieve this.

You can use [**Azure private DNS**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview) for private domains:

[image]

In this scenario, you can configure zones names with a split-horizon view - allowing a private and a public DNS zone to share the same name.

> you can use all common DNS records types. Azure DNS supports A, AAAA,
>   CNAME, MX, NS, PTR, SOA, SRV, and TXT records.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx for the answer. private fqdns *do* have `.internal.cloudapp.net` tho. This is a paid-for feature and not yet ready for production, but still good to know.